Malloc not properly allocating memory
I had to write a small C program that would read from stdin and create a linked list using malloc. However, when I was writing the program a certain way, malloc did not appropriately manage the memory at all. Please help me.
read.c
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "expr.h"

void print_list(List *exprs)
{
    for (List *p = exprs; p != NULL; p = p->next) {
        if (p != exprs) {
            printf(" ");
        }
        assert(p->expr != NULL);
        print_expr_node(p->expr);
    }
}

int main()
{
    List *exprs = get_all_expr_nodes();
    assert(exprs != NULL);
    print_list(exprs);
    printf("\n");
}

expr.h
#pragma once

typedef enum exprType {
    NONE = 0,
    NUMBER,
    ADD,
    SUB,
    MUL,
    DIV,
    END,
} ExprType;

typedef struct expr {
    ExprType type;

    union {
        int val;

        struct {
            struct expr *left;
            struct expr *right;
        } binop;
    } u;
} Expr;

typedef struct list {
    Expr        *expr;
    struct list *next;
} List;

extern Expr *get_next_expr_node();
extern List *get_all_expr_nodes();
extern void  print_expr_node(Expr *expr);

expr.c
#include "expr.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void set_num_expr(Expr **expr, int val)
{
    (*expr)->type  = NUMBER;
    (*expr)->u.val = val;
}

static void set_op_expr(Expr **expr, char *s)
{
    switch (*s) {
    case '+':
        (*expr)->type = ADD;
        break;
    case '-':
        (*expr)->type = SUB;
        break;
    case '*':
        (*expr)->type = MUL;
        break;
    case '/':
        (*expr)->type = DIV;
        break;
    default:
        (*expr)->type = END;
    }
}

extern void print_expr_node(Expr *expr)
{
    switch (expr->type) {
    case NUMBER:
        printf("%d", expr->u.val);
        break;
    case ADD:
        printf("+");
        break;
    case SUB:
        printf("-");
        break;
    case MUL:
        printf("*");
        break;
    case DIV:
        printf("/");
        break;
    }
}

static void print_debug(Expr *expr)
{
    printf("Expr Address: %x\n", expr);
    printf("Expr Value: ");
    print_expr_node(expr);
    printf("\n\n");
}

extern List *get_all_expr_nodes(void)
{
    Expr *expr = get_next_expr_node();
    if (expr->type == END)
        return NULL;
    List *head = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List));
    head->expr = expr;
    print_debug(head->expr);
    head->next = get_all_expr_nodes();
    return head;
}

static Expr *num_expr(int val)
{
    Expr *e  = (Expr *)malloc(sizeof(Expr));
    e->type  = NUMBER;
    e->u.val = val;
    return e;
}

static Expr *op_expr(char *s)
{
    Expr *e = (Expr *)malloc(sizeof(Expr));
    switch (*s) {
    case '+':
        e->type = ADD;
        break;
    case '-':
        e->type = SUB;
        break;
    case '*':
        e->type = MUL;
        break;
    case '/':
        e->type = DIV;
        break;
    default:
        e->type = END;
    }
    return e;
}

extern Expr *get_next_expr_node(void)
{
    /* Expr *expr = (Expr *)malloc(sizeof(Expr)); */
    char s;
    scanf("%s", &s);
    int val = atoi(&s);
    if (val) {
        /* set_num_expr(&expr, val); */
        return num_expr(val);
    } else {
        /* set_op_expr(&expr, &s); */
        return op_expr(&s);
    }
    /* return expr; */
}

Specifically the last function in expr.c, extern Expr *get_next_expr_node(void);, when I wrote it like above worked fine.
I redirect a testcase like below into the program, and it prints the Expr addresses and the correct linked list at the end (which are just the terms in order).
t463.stdin
13
39
*
56
*
83
67
+
23
-
-

output
Expr Address: 2b951e0
Expr Value: 13

Expr Address: 2b95200
Expr Value: 39

Expr Address: 2b95220
Expr Value: *

Expr Address: 2b95240
Expr Value: 56

Expr Address: 2b95260
Expr Value: *

Expr Address: 2b95280
Expr Value: 83

Expr Address: 2b90000
Expr Value: 67

Expr Address: 2b90020
Expr Value: +

Expr Address: 2b90040
Expr Value: 23

Expr Address: 2b90060
Expr Value: -

Expr Address: 2b90080
Expr Value: -

13 39 * 56 * 83 67 + 23 - -

When I re-write extern Expr *get_next_expr_node(void); in another way however, malloc did not work.
extern Expr *get_next_expr_node(void)
{
    Expr *expr = (Expr *)malloc(sizeof(Expr));
    char  s;
    scanf("%s", &s);
    int val = atoi(&s);
    if (val) {
        set_num_expr(&expr, val);
        /* return num_expr(val); */
    } else {
        set_op_expr(&expr, &s);
        /* return op_expr(&s); */
    }
    return expr;
}

Running the same testcase, I get this output.
Expr Address: 1700033
Expr Value: 13

Expr Address: 1700039
Expr Value: 39

Expr Address: 1705200
Expr Value: *

Expr Address: 1700036
Expr Value: 56

Expr Address: 1705200
Expr Value: *

Expr Address: 1700033
Expr Value: 83

Expr Address: 1700037
Expr Value: 67

Expr Address: 1705200
Expr Value: +

Expr Address: 1700033
Expr Value: 23

Expr Address: 1705300
Expr Value: -

Expr Address: 1705300
Expr Value: -

23  +  + 23 67 + 23 - -

What I can see is that malloc re-uses addresses, some not word-aligned, and the gaps between a couple are not adequate space, so the final linked list is wrong but miraculously intact. I don't know what the change in my code is that causes malloc to behave so unexpectedly like this.

char  s; scanf("%s", &s); - where is null terminator stored?

%s format is for a null-terminated string. If you're only reading a single character use scanf(" %c", &s);

atoi() also requires a null-terminated string. Use fgets() to read a line of input, then convert that to a number.

if (val) is not how you tell if the input was a number or an operator. If the number is 0 you'll treat it as an operator.

You're causing undefined behavior because of these problems with reading the input. malloc() has nothing to do with it.

@Barmar I admit my code is a bit shortcut-y with reading the input, but I don't believe there are any problems with it. My code has already passed all the test cases (a couple hundred files). Unless you are implying this is why my second solution does not run as expected? I could take a look at it.

That's the thing about undefined behavior: you can test the heck out of it and not see any problems, and then when you're no longer expecting it... boom! Bug. Make sure to compile with warnings enabled. For GCC/Clang: -Wall -Wextra -Werror

Side note: Start by simplifying. Avoid "double star" pointers (e.g. Expr **). set_num_expr and set_op_expr can [and should] change the arg Expr **expr to Expr *expr with requisite changes elsewhere. In the body (*expr)->type --> expr->type. In caller: &expr --> expr

It's quite common that when you cause undefined behavior, it shows up as a problem with something totally unrelated. There are many questions here of the form "Why does adding/removing a printf change the result?", and it's practically always due to undefined behavior.

Memory problems like this can come and go depending on how the memory is perturbed, like by adding a call to malloc. Compiling with an Address Sanitizer makes memory usage more strict and immediately finds the problem.
$ cc -Wall -Wshadow -Wwrite-strings -Wextra -Wconversion -std=c17 -pedantic -g -fsanitize=address   -c -o test.o test.c
$ cc -fsanitize=address  test.o   -o test
$ ./test
13
=================================================================
==18673==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x7ff7b409ed81 at pc 0x00010c87b09a bp 0x7ff7b409ec20 sp 0x7ff7b409e3b0
WRITE of size 3 at 0x7ff7b409ed81 thread T0
39    #0 0x10c87b099 in scanf_common(void*, int, bool, char const*, __va_list_tag*)+0x13e9 (libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x3f099)
    #1 0x10c87bb8b in wrap_scanf+0xfb (libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x3fb8b)
    #2 0x10be60f47 in get_next_expr_node test.c:135
    #3 0x10be6182c in get_all_expr_nodes test.c:152
    #4 0x10be61b23 in main test.c:177
    #5 0x7ff810177385 in start+0x795 (dyld:x86_64+0xfffffffffff5c385)

That's this.
    char s;
    scanf("%s", &s);

That's trying to use a single character buffer for input and it's overflowing memory.

You need to allocate sufficient space, initialize the buffer, and restrict scanf to not read more than the buffer.
    char s[1024] = "";
    scanf("%1023s", s);

I've used a large input buffer to ensure the whole input is read, using a small buffer risks leaving some input on stdin and confusing later reads. The buffer will be recycled.
We have to initialize the buffer because if scanf fails we don't want atoi trying to read uninitialized garbage.
scanf has a lot of problems. If you just need to read a line of input, use fgets. It's much safer.
    char s[1024] = "";
    fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin);


Detail, "We have to initialize the buffer because if scanf fails we don't want atoi trying to read uninitialized garbage." --> Some failures can leave s  in an undefined state.  Better to check the return value of scanf()/fgets() --> char s[1024]; if (scanf("%1023s", s) != 1) Handle_Error;.
